# Get Association Counts With Fastest Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums

I'm looking for the best performance query to get the count of different enums from an association.

Take the following SQL

```
CREATE TYPE ITEM_TYPE AS ENUM ('coming', 'new', 'archive');

CREATE TABLE centers
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);

CREATE TABLE items
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  center_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES centers(id),
  item_type ITEM_TYPE NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

I'm looking to query all of the "Centers" but I also wanted to return the item counts based on the item_type enum.

In the below example ItemNewCount and ItemArchiveCount are related to the enum.

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Center Name',
    ItemComingCount: 400,
    ItemNewCount: 300,
    ItemArchiveCount: 567
}
```

Comment: what does it mean? ItemNewCount: 300, ItemArchiveCount: 567

Comment: @Vecchiasignora I've updated the question. Basically, those counts are the different enums so there should actually be 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine `left join, group by and Case` operators

try this

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, 
sum(case when i.item_type = 'coming' then 1 else 0 end) as ItemComingCount,
sum(case when i.item_type = 'new' then 1 else 0 end) as ItemNewCount,
sum(case when i.item_type = 'archive' then 1 else 0 end) as ItemArchiveCount
from centers as c LEFT JOIN items as i ON c.id = i.center_id
group by c.id, c.name
```

Comment: Magic :) Thank you sir!